# При расшифровании закрытого текста, расшифровывается только до первого пробела,т.е. было " Stack overflow", стало "Stack"

Tags: c++

```
    extern "C" char* __declspec(dllexport) Viziner_shif(int key, string text, int dlina)
{
    char alphabet [11][12]={
    {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L',},
    {'M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X',},
    {'Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j',},
    {'k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v',},
    {'w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7',},
    {'8','9','А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И',},
    {'Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т','У','Ф',},
    {'Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я','а',},
    {'б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л',},
    {'м','н','о','п','р','с','т','у','ф','х','ц','ч',},
    {'ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я',',','.','/',' ',},
    };

   char* rez = new char[200];
   int n = 0;
   Label:
   for(int q = n; q < dlina; q++)
   {

     for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
     {
       for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
       {
        if(text[q] == alphabet[i][j])
        {
          i = (i+((j+key)/12))%11;
          j = (j+key)%12;
          rez[q] = alphabet[i][j];
          n++;
          goto Label;
        };
       };
     };
   };
    delete [] rez;
  return rez;

}

extern "C" char* __declspec(dllexport) Viziner_deshif(int key, string text, int dlina)
{
    char alphabet [11][12]={
    {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L',},
    {'M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X',},
    {'Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j',},
    {'k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v',},
    {'w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7',},
    {'8','9','А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И',},
    {'Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т','У','Ф',},
    {'Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я','а',},
    {'б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л',},
    {'м','н','о','п','р','с','т','у','ф','х','ц','ч',},
    {'ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я',',','.','/',' ',},
    };

   char* rez = new char[50];
   int n = 0;
   Label:
   for(int q = n; q < dlina; q++)
   {
     for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
     {
       for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
       {
        if(text[q] == alphabet[i][j])
        {
          i = (j-key) >= 0 ? i : i-abs(j-key)/12-1;
          j = (j-key) >= 0 ? j-key : (11*12+j-key)%12;
          rez[q] = alphabet[i][j];
          n++;
          goto Label;
        };
       };
     };
   };
  delete [] rez;
  return rez;

}
```

Comment: Меня одного goto смутило? - или все на delete[] смотрят?

Comment: @Andrey: Способ организации итерирования по строке в коде - это какой-то страшнейший и дичайший ужас, летящий на крыльях ночи (с этим `goto`). Но он "какбэ работает", пока символ из строки успешно находится в таблице. (Да, если символ вдруг не найдется, то все сразу накроется медным тазом, но это отдельная история). Потому я сфокусировался пока на остальных проблемах, т.е. на обработке "хороших" строк.

Comment: @AnT я думаю на это не надо тратить время. Одного взгляда хватило для появления боли в глазах.

Comment: @AnT меня больше испугало расшифрованное... нет бы aes из openssl взять или ГОСТ там с тк26...

Comment: @Andrey: Реализация шифра Вижнера - популярное учебное задание. Правда какое отношение вышеприведенный код имеет к шифру Вижнера - вопрос отдельный. По-моему это какая-то странная реализация элементарного шифра Цезаря, которую кто-то обманным путем пытается замаскировать под реализацию шифра Вижнера )))

Comment: @AnT так много вопросов...

Answer (score 3):

Так а что это за белиберда вообще

```
delete [] rez;
return rez;
```

Вы возвращаете указатель на массив который только что сами уничтожили. Так что нет, никакого "расшифровывается только до первого пробела" в вашем коде нет. Ваш код не работает никак вообще.

Отдельно не ясно, чего вы пытались достичь, соорудив такую невероятную логику итерирования по строке - то, как процессе участвуют переменные `q` и `n` с этим `goto`. Также, если вы собираетесь формировать результат в С-строке, то вам нужно не забывать добавлять в нее нулевой терминатор.

---

Попробуем дешифровать латинскую `A` с `key = 1`. В таблице это позиция `i = 0`, `j = 0`. Формула для `i` в дешифраторе сразу дает `i = -1`. Дальше можно не смотреть - код полезет в массив по отрицательному индексу. То есть ваши навороченные загадочные формулы в коде - это какая-то белиберда. Разбирайтесь и переписывайте.

Латинская `A` - это, кстати, то, во что превращается символ пробела в `"Stack Overflow"` при `key = 1`. Неудивительно, что у вас в ваших экспериментах строка обрубалась - при дешифровке вы непонятно откуда из памяти тащили какой-то мусор, который запросто мог оказаться нулем.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101423/discussion-on-answer-by-ant-----).